# ASP.NET unable select and Update

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, select, insert-update

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MCDU11;Initial Catalog=VisitorManagement;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SecurityUser WHERE Username = '" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "' AND "
                                        + "Password='" + Encrypt(txtPassword.Text.Trim()) + "'" , conn);

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update SecurityUser set LoginOn ='" + DateTime.Now + "' , " + "WHERE Username ='" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "'", conn);
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr;

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    if (dr.Read())
    {

        Session["Username"] = txtUsername.Text;
        Session["Id"] = dr["Id"].ToString();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("SecurityHome.aspx");

    }
    else
    {
        lblError.Text = "Either username and/or password is wrong. Please try again!";
    }

    dr.Close();
    conn.Close();


}
```

this my error

> "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There is already an open DataReader associated
>   with this Command which must be closed first."

Comment: please use parameterized queries !!!! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add MultipleActiveResultSets=True in your connection
as

```
 SqlConnection conn =
new SqlConnection("Data Source=MCDU11;
Initial Catalog=VisitorManagement;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
```

and

```
    SqlCommand cmd1 = 
new SqlCommand("update SecurityUser set LoginOn ='" + DateTime.Now + "' 
WHERE Username ='" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "'",conn);
```

Comment: hi thank for the help they show me this error, "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'."

Comment: it is different error related to you sql statement in cmd1, see updated result

Answer (score 0):

> "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command
>   which must be closed first."

The exception message is so clear enough, you cannot execute any commands for the connection (another DataReader, NonQuery ...), until the original DataReader is closed.
In your cases, the code that throw exception is

```
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You should extract your code into 2 motheds, the first one will be get the data from DB and the second one will update if step#1 is successful.

**For demonstration:**

```
private static string ConnectionString = "Data Source=MCDU11;Initial Catalog=VisitorManagement;Integrated Security=True";

protected string GetLoggedUserId(string username, string password) {
    var id = string.Empty;
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString) {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SecurityUser WHERE Username = '" + username + "' AND "
                                        + "Password='" + password)  + "'" , conn);
        conn.Open();
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
            if(reader.Read()){
                id = reader["Id"].ToString();
            }   
        }
    } 
    return id;
}

protected string UpdateLoggedUser(string username) {
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString) {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("update SecurityUser set LoginOn ='" + DateTime.Now + "' , " + "WHERE Username ='" + username + "'", conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } 
}

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    var loggedId = GetLoggedUserId(txtUsername.Text.Trim(),Encrypt(txtPassword.Text.Trim()));

    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(loggedId))
    {
        UpdateLoggedUser(txtUsername.Text.Trim());
        Response.Redirect("SecurityHome.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        lblError.Text = "Either username and/or password is wrong. Please try again!";
    }   
}
```

According to MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

User **DataAdapter**. It is faster than DataReader and It also disconnected oriented architecture

```
    string connString = "Data Source=MCDU11;Initial Catalog=VisitorManagement;Integrated Security=True";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SecurityUser WHERE Username = '" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "' AND "
                                        + "Password='" + Encrypt(txtPassword.Text.Trim()) + "'" , conn);

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update SecurityUser set LoginOn ='" + DateTime.Now + "' , " + "WHERE Username ='" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "'", conn);
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))  
{

    using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(
            cmd, conn))
    {
                DataTable t = new DataTable();
                a.Fill(t);

       if (t.Rows.Count > 0)
       {

        Session["Username"] = txtUsername.Text;
        Session["Id"] = t[0]["Id"].ToString();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("SecurityHome.aspx");

       }
       else
       {
        lblError.Text = "Either username and/or password is wrong. Please try again!";
       }

   }

   }
```